# Strategy for CORS - issue with IE10 : xhr status returns 0 for HTTP 401

Tags: apache, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-10, cors, virtualhost

I have the following setup on my server:

- Apache HTTP Server is serving a BackboneJS frontend application
- Apache Tomcat is serving a Java based backend (CORS enabled).

Everything is running on a single server that I have full control over.

I'm currently using `com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter` in the Java based backend to enable CORS. Everything seens to be working fine.

My frontend has the following code to redirect the user to the login page in case an un-authenticated REST call occurred:

```
$.ajaxSetup({

    statusCode: {
        401: function(){
            window.location.replace('/#login');

        },

        403: function() {
            window.location.replace('/#denied');
        }
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Everything works fine on all major browsers except for IE10.

In IE10, when the non-authenticated users calls the REST serverm the server returns an HTTP 401 (as it should). The XHR object I'm seeing in the IE debugger hoewever seems to have translated this into `status = 0`.  (On chrome you can cleary see that it has `status = 401`.

This appears to be [a bug in IE10](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785990/ie-10-on-win8-does-not-assign-the-correct-status-to-xmlhttprequest-when-the-result-is-401) where IE10 is treating HTTP status 401 as a network error. The console shows:

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied
```

- Is there a way to workaround this ? 
  I can add handling for statusCode 0 in the `ajaxSetup` but that seems more of a hack.
- Is there a way to disable CORS altogether through some kind of Apache / Tomcat configuration ?

Currently my apache configuration is setup using vhosts so that the following public URLs map their corresponding internal hostname / ports.

```
http://mywebapp.com -> http://myrealservername:8080/   -> /var/www/http
http://myrestapi.com -> http://myrealservername:8088/  -> /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/restapi
```

Would it be possible / advisable to have Apache

- continue serving the static webapp from http://mywebapp.com/restapi
- exposing the REST API on http://mywebapp.com/restapi (keeping it "inside" the webapp).

If such a setup were possible I wouldn't need CORS anymore ? It would keep things a lot simpler while increasing browser support ?

Comment: I have the same issue. You solve it?

Comment: For the moment I just packaged everything up in the same app to avoid using CORS. (Supporting IE8 / IE9 was a hard requirement). But I'm still interested in other thoughts and ideas.

Comment: If you want to keep the projects separate can't you avoid CORS issues by deploying one that runs at url: http://myapp.com/webstuff/ and another that runs at url http://myapp.com/reststuff/ ? You should be able to config apache to handle webstuff urls itself and let tomcat handle the rest. Not that I know how to do that configuration, but it should be possible.

Comment: Also, you might want to re-write or change this question. It's confusing because you title it as a CORS issue, but the real issue is your IE 10 ajax one right, which is not necessarily CORS related is it? I mean for you they are related, but wouldn't you still be returning 401 if they are running on the same domain?

Comment: Same issue here, get a 403 on IE10 only

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XmlHttpRequest status 0 instead of 401 in IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081267/xmlhttprequest-status-0-instead-of-401-in-ie-10)