# No headers available in xhr object when an UNAUTHORIZED error occurs - IE10

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2

I have a CORS Ajax call to a web api. I have a message handler which throws an:

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Oops!!!" };
throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
```

On the client I can't get no response headers, tried:

```
error: function (xhr, error) {
var result = xhr.getResponseHeader("Response");
```

but result is null and no other heades are available.
The Debugger shows correctly a 401!

Should I return the Unauthorized Exception differently from the server?

Update:
I forgot the add the Origin header to my HttpResponseException, in order to get the headers.

But in IE10 I don't get any headers, only error message

> "error"

How can I know what happend, when using IE10?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19207372/2581562) is related question.

Answer (score 0):

As I cannot get the Headers when returning a 401 response.
No instead I return NoContent StatusCode, which triggers the AJAX success eventhandler. 
Now I have to check the response header "response" (which I manually add on the server side) in the success eventhandler, in order to make it work in IE 10:

**Server:**

```
var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent) { ReasonPhrase = "UNAUTHORIZED" };
msg.Headers.Add("RESPONSE", "401");
AddCORSHeaders(msg.Headers, request);
return await Task.FromResult(msg);
```

**Client:**

```
 error: function (jqXhr, error) {
           var isAuth= jqXhr.getResponseHeader("Response");
```

Now I get a "response" header with value 401.

IF SOMEONE HAS A BETTER APPROACH, I'LL EXCEPT THE ANSWER !

In IE10 the ajax error eventhandler you get readyState=0 and status="".
In Chrome you get a 401 and readyState=4.