# IE is not handleing 401 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have an ajax call that is partly used to check to see if you are logged in.

```
function userInfo(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://api.itassistteam.com/api/account/isloggedon",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        statusCode: {
            401: function(){
                console.log("401 error.");
                deleteCookie();
                window.location.href = "./login.html";
            }
        },
    });
}
```

In Chrome, FF and Opera, it redirects to the log in page like it's supposed to, but in IE it does nothing. When I look in the console, it says

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

Any idea why IE will not take the error handler and redirect to login? The "401 error." message does not appear in the console.

Comment: I've found this is a bug in IE. I had to change the code to where error is handling what I would do for 401. This is NOT ideal. I found this other question someone had posted with pretty much the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081267/xmlhttprequest-status-0-instead-of-401-in-ie-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of statusCode I used error. This is how you get the same results with error that you would get with

```
statusCode : {
    401: function(){...}
}
```

You do,

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    if(jqXHR.status == 401){
        ...
    }
}
```

This is consistent across all major browsers unlike the statusCode method witch doesn't work with IE. This way you can have error handling specific to the error in IE.