# Jquery ajax reports 404 not 401 in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a web app that uses the google drive api to upload a file. If the authentication expires, we get a 401 returned which allows the app to reauthenticate and try again. This works fine in Chrome, a 401 is returned and everything is rosy.

However in IE10, jqXHR.status is 404 not 401. When I look in the IE network profiler, the request does actually return 401 but its not what jquery is giving:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/0B_Z9rTaY-rm0T2xGRC1LcjdrTnM?uploadType=multipart  
PUT 401 application/json    508 B   
437 ms  XMLHttpRequest  74272   0   374 0   0   433979
```

Console error in IE

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

The example ajax call

```
$.ajax("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files" + up + "?uploadType=multipart", {
    data: data,
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + self.authResult.access_token},
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: fileId != null ? 'PUT' : 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        log.debug("upload complete");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errorCode = jqXHR.status;
        log.error("failed to upload file " + errorCode);
    }
}
```

The following is a similar question but I'm already doing the suggested resolution of using the error callback:

[IE is not handleing 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285031/ie-is-not-handleing-401-error)

I need to identify that it is actually a 401 error so that I can start the re-authentication process. Why is the 401 hidden and how can I identify that it was actually an authentication error that caused the request to fail?

Comment: what are you asking? why does it do that? how to handle it?

Comment: Hi Phil. I have added that to the question. I want to know whether the put failed with a 401. It appears to be a jquery/IE bug so any background info to help put me on track would be great. Thanks!