# IE11 XMLRequest Access is Denied

Tags: javascript, exception, xmlhttprequest, cors, internet-explorer-11

I tried to do a simple AJAX request on `http://localhost:8080/` and I get an error right away when using IE 11. I don't think IE is even trying to send anything.

Did somebody meet this issue?

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sRHp8/2/) showing this behavior,

html:

```
<button id='btn1'>launch</button>
```

onLoad:

```
var xhr,btn=document.getElementById('btn1');
btn.onclick=onButton;

var onReadyState=function(){
  console.log('ready state:'+_xhr.readyState);
  if(xhr.readyState===4){
    console.log('status:'+_xhr.status);
  }
}

function onButton(){
  xhr=new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange=onReadyState;
  xhr.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/ScanAPI/v1/client');
  xhr.send();
}
```

You will need to launch the IE F12 developer tool, before trying and you will see IE catching the exception.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are referencing an object named `_xhr` that does not exist within the scope of the `onReadyState` function.

You should be using `this` instead :

```
var onReadyState = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log('status :' + this.status);
    }
};
```

That's because the `XMLHttpRequest` object will call back `onReadyState` with its own context, which is accessible through `this` in your function.

Also note that the `onReadyState` function misses a semi-colon at the end of its definition, didn't notice it at first sight.

**EDIT :** I also noticed that IE10 (and IE11) does interpret [some HTTP response code as *network errors*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081267/xmlhttprequest-status-0-instead-of-401-in-ie-10) (such as with a `401` response code), if it is your case, then it makes sense that IE fails at retrieving your resource.

I forked your fiddle and [wrote a simple page](http://jsfiddle.net/qT6Kr/1/) that works well with IE11.

Comment: That's a good point Halim, but it won't impact the result because the exception occurs at the xhr.open and the onReadyState function is never called.

Comment: What error code does your web service return at the point at which you get an error ? Could you check it ? I've edited my response and also created a fiddle that works perfectly with both Chrome and IE11. Also, are you sure that you are not having an error due to CORS (using 127.0.0.1 in you website instead of localhost for instance) ?

Comment: You're right, using ``127.0.0.1`` instead of ``localhost`` did work!

Comment: When using ``localhost`` the service wasn't hit by the request, the exception was occurring during the open call. Of course this works in FireFox, and Chrome. I didn't suspect that in first place because my preliminary testing with IE11 and the local html file worked fine. It started to failed when I hosted the html file in a different server.