# IE10 interprets status codes 401/403 as network error

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have an AngularJS `responseError` interceptor that broadcasts events for 401 and 403 HTTP status codes. But there is a bug in IE10 ([according to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16320339/1053611)) when it gets a 401 status code from the server (not logged in) or 403 (not authorized), IE interprets this as a network error, so the `responseError` interceptor is never fired, thus the user is never redirected to the login page.

Code:

```
app.factory('authHttpInterceptor', ["$rootScope", "AUTH_EVENTS", "$q", function ($rootScope, AUTH_EVENTS, $q) {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            return config;
        },
        'requestError': function (rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        'response': function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast({
                401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
                403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized
            }[rejection.status], rejection);
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8iZQjFM.png]

Is there any solution to this?

**Edit:** `response` interceptor is fired and I was going to check there if the status was 401 or 403 and then broadcast it from there, but it's only fired if the response is a success (200 OK).

**Edit 2:** It turns out the `responseError` interceptor gets called, but with status code `0`.

**Edit 3:** I'm solving this by adding `0: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,` because if we receive HTTP status code 0, clearly something is wrong.

Comment: is responseError never called, or is it just never called with one of your two expected status codes. If it gets called with statusCode 0, you could at least catch that and come up with a workaround.

Comment: I can't quite say because the only known error by the API is either 401 or 403.

Comment: Would be easy to test for, simply add a console.log(rejection) before the broadcast.

Comment: Okay I checked and it gets called with status code 0.

Comment: This issue is still exist in IE10 & Microsoft closed this issue as not reproducible.

Comment: I just ran into this problem today. After trying a few workarounds, and some Googleing, I ended up here. 
It turned out to just be a security level settings. 
Whatever security zone your website is in (Internet Options > Security) make sure you ENABLE the following setting in your zone: Miscellaneous > Access data sources across domains. This is only workaround

Comment: Then you can at least intercept that status code and handle it as an unknown network error (or possibly parse the statusText or responseText to try to figure out what kind of error it is)

Comment: @pankajparkar i'm sure that would fix it, but... surely you can't expect your users to have to do that

Comment: @KevinB obviously no.. i'll never do that..

Comment: Would it make sense to create an issue in the AngularJS project, because I analyzed the HTTP response and it clearly states 401.

Comment: I wouldn't, since it's not a bug in angularjs, but that's just me.

Comment: But AngularJS is said to support IE10 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [bug in Internet Explorer 10](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/785990/ie-10-on-win8-does-not-assign-the-correct-status-to-xmlhttprequest-when-the-result-is-401) and was closed by Microsoft as *not reproducible*. The bug lets IE interpret 401 status codes from the server as a network error, so it's impossible to determine whether the user is unauthorized or simply lost internet connection.

I solved this by adding `0` as an error event, so when receiving status code `0` it broadcasts the `notAuthenticated` event. According to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) there is no status code `0` so when receiving it, means something went wrong.

I changed the interceptor to the following:

```
'responseError': function (rejection) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast({
        0: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated, // Edge case, if status code from server is 0, clearly something is wrong
        401: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthenticated,
        403: AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized
    }[rejection.status], rejection);
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, IE 10 gives me a status of -1, which is also the status I get for generic network errors.

Comment: Be careful treat 0 as 401. When you cancel a request it also run into 0 case.